# Activities don't show on the profile page

Tags: civicase, activities

[image]

This child has three activities linked to his profile, however they don't show up. The do show up if we navigate to cases, but we would like to see them from this profile view. Is there any way I can get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case activities usually don't show on the "non-case" side of things, like on their user record. As to why it shows "3" on the tab there that might be the theme since I don't see it counting them on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. Looks like maybe shoreditch theme?

Comment: We have a combo of shoreditch, user profile custom layouts, and civicase extensions, so it is a bit of a jumble :D We can see his cases from the profile but not the activities. I will disable that link in the side if it is not normally there.

Comment: The link is normally there, but the count of 3 is normally zero if they only have case activities. You can have an activity that is not a case activity, like a contribution for example.